# Overwriting disk with random data vs. encrypted zeros

Tags: disk-encryption, deletion, luks

Most disk encryption guides recommend to overwrite the disk with random data before encryption, this is discussed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26594/filling-the-disk-with-random-data-prior-to-encryption).

However the time this takes with the "standard" source of random data can be rather slow:

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb1 bs=10M
29+1 records in
29+0 records out
304087040 bytes (304 MB) copied, 15.5476 s, 19.6 MB/s
```

On an encrypted device (specifically, with LUKS), are there any drawbacks when one just fills the *encrypted* partition with zeros?

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/data bs=50M
1099+0 records in
1099+0 records out
57619251200 bytes (58 GB) copied, 306.091 s, 188 MB/s
```

The only problem I could see would be that if known-plaintext attacks surface, this method might give an attacker plenty of sample data to play with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filling an encrypted volume with zeroes is the recommended method for overwriting a disk in the [cryptsetup FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#2-setup) (section 2.19).

Use a throwaway key so that the resulting ciphertext no longer corresponds to a known plaintext under your actual key.

Comment: Good point about using another key for this step!

Comment: Just a question : what are the theoretical risks of using the same key as the encrypted data ? The attacker will not be able to tell that the data is in fact encrypted zeroes, as the disk is encrypted.

Comment: The Arch Linux Wiki has an [extensive article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk) about wiping storage devices. In particular, take a look at the [advanced dd example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk/Tips_and_tricks#dd_-_advanced_example) in the Tips & Tricks.